# ODOO - Add image field as background in CSS

Tags: css, odoo, background-image, odoo-10

Here's the issue, I want to pickup an image from my backend `website.image_url(employee,'image_medium' )`

It works when I use it with `<img t-att-src="website.image_url(employee,'image_medium' )" />`

But as soon as I try to use as CSS attibute, it doesn't work. How can I solve the issue?

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;website.image_url(employee, 'image_medium')&quot;);">
```

Comment: have you tried : `<div style="background-image: url('website.image_url(employee, 'image_medium')');">` ? CSS do not understand &quot; as a " but a set of characters :) even then , not sure that it will be parsed and updated from a style attribute

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work either...

Comment: try escaping the inner single quotes `<div style="background-image: url('website.image_url(employee, \'image_medium\')');">`

Comment: Actually `url()` doesn't need quotes. So try `<div style="background-image: url(website.image_url(employee, 'image_medium'));">`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('"website.image_url(employee, 'image_medium')"');">
```

The single quotes withing you call to get the image I think are what is breaking the css as it thinks the first is ending the url.

url also doesn't actually need single quotes, so you can also try:

```
<div style="background-image: url("website.image_url(employee, 'image_medium')");">
```

Comment: Both of these answers will likely not work, because the first answer has single quotes inside single quotes and the second answer has double quotes inside double quotes.